# Division in Sql returning 0 or NULL

Tags: sql, case

New to SQL and trying to figure this one out. I’m expecting a ratio of win % but am getting a 0 or null column

```
With previous as (select Venue, Row,

Count(case when place = 1 then 1 else null end) as firstx
Count(case when place = 2 then 1 else null end) as secondx
Count(case when place = 3 then 1 else null end) as thirdx 
Count(case when place Between 1 and 15 then 1 else null end) as allplaces 

From horses
Where racetitle not like ‘%stand%’
Group by venue, row)

Select case
When firstx = 0
Then Null
Else round(firstx/allplaces, 2)
End as winratio
From previous
Where allplaces > 10;
```

I want to do this with secondx and thirdx but am not sure why it is returning a column as 0 or Null???

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: This is due to "integer division" rules (when you divide one integer by another the result is an integer). Easiest way to avoid it is to simply force one of the integers to be a decimal, e.g. `round(1.0 * firstx/allplaces, 2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `NULL` because `firstx = 0` and `0` because the rdbms that you use does integer division when dividing `firstx/allplaces`, so multiply by `1.0` before you divide:

```
With previous as (
  select Venue, Row,
         Count(case when place = 1 then 1 end) as firstx
         Count(case when place = 2 then 1 end) as secondx
         Count(case when place = 3 then 1 end) as thirdx 
         Count(case when place Between 1 and 15 then 1 end) as allplaces 
  From horses
  Where racetitle not like ‘%stand%’
  Group by venue, row
)
Select case
  When firstx = 0 Then Null
  Else round(1.0 * firstx/allplaces, 2)
End as winratio
From previous
Where allplaces > 10;
```

I also simplified the `CASE` expressions inside `COUNT()` because there is no need for `else NULL` since this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your DBMS makes *integer division* when `/` operates on integers. And since `firstx` is in general less than `allplaces`, then integer division of them is 0

You need to cast of of the values to a decimal number. The syntax depends on specific DBMS, usually it's `CAST` or `CONVERT` function

Answer (score 0):

Some databases do integer division, which is probably the issue you are facing.  That said, the more canonical way to prevent a divide-by-zero is to use `nullif()`:

```
select round(firstx * 1.0/ nullif(allplaces, 0), 2) as winratio
```

`nullif()` is a standard SQL function and available in almost all databases.